# Force HTTPS on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl-certificate

Sorry, newbie here. I had this as my .htaccess file and it used to force HTTPS everywhere, now it doesn't work anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated... hit a dead end after way too many hours of investigating.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: So what did you change in your setup so that things changed?

Comment: Did you check if that file get's considered at all any more? How?

Comment: Yes, because those last two lines are still doing what they are supposed to... nothing new in the setup other than upgrading PHP

Comment: All I want to do is force HTTPS across the entire website if any has a better way?

Comment: So what does `%{HTTPS}` actually contain in case of a non ssl request?

Comment: I thought that was just a lookup to see if the URL contained HTTPS, and if not then it changed the URL so that it did (next line)

Comment: Sure, that is correct. That line you use works by comparing the variable %{HTTPS} with the literal string "off". Since the rule does not get applied according to your observation I wonder what that variable actually contains in your setup.

Comment: Have a try using that instead: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`

Comment: Just tried that - no success :-(

Comment: Next step would be to enable request logging in your http server's rewriting module. That allows to follow in detail each step inside your rewriting engine.